# Keep button relative to screen when ajax on-click changing the content above

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way to make `<a/>` tag do not scroll on click at all? Or rather I want it to be scrolled to the same place it was before click with the screen shuttering reduced to the minimum. The thing is that this `<a/>` tag changes the content of the `<div/>` with ajax located above the `<a/>`, and I want `<a/>` to remain exactly in the same position relative to position on the screen.

Basically I have next code:

```
<div id='content'></div>
<div class="pagination-container">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a id='skipToNext' href='#/' rel="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
 $('#skipToNext).on("click", function(evt) {
  $.ajax({ url: "...."})
   .done(function(e) {
      $("#content").html(e);
    });
}

</script>
```

when the ajax can return the data of different size, I would like for the `<a/>` to stay exactly the same, so I could click on it many times without changing the mouse position.

Please note that this is actually a pager, so only `<a/>` is available and not `<button/>` if this makes any difference.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/kcfrp3L0/

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for that? For example position your `a` elements with fixed positioning.

Comment: @makshh can you provide an example? I worked very little with `css` unfortunately

Comment: @makshh also note that I'm using `bootstrap`, maybe I can use it to pin the button? I haven't thought of that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS for that, for example:

```
#skipToNext {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Your button will be always in the top right corner (always relative to the window).

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kcfrp3L0/3/)

Comment: This worked greatly, although I had to dance a bit additionaly, like setting `margin-bottom` to `body` content. Also `bootstrap` provides `<footer class='footer'></footer>` which can be used instead of custom css. But still great answer, thanks!